# notepad++ delete lines that match

Tags: notepad++

I didn't have any luck googling or know how to search for it.

I would appreciate any help I could get.

I would like to remove all lines that match on notepad++.

**Example:**
Game1
Game2
Game3
Game4
Game1
Game2
Game3
Game4
Game5

**Output:**
Game5

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried yourself? What language are you using? Notepad++ supports several.

Comment: All the lines that match what ?

Answer (score 1):

`Search` > `Find`

Find What: `^((?!Game5).)*$`

Select (`*`) Regular Expression

Click `Replace`: Replace With: *blank*

And Click `Replace All`